# How to delete a row from a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a responsive data table that adds a row each time I click on a add button that is in the end of the row. And the add button turns into a delete button. Here's the code I made

For the Table:

```
<table id="invoice_table_data">
<tr id="last_row">
        <td contenteditable id="item_name"></td>
        <td contenteditable id="item_code"></td>
        <td contenteditable id="description"></td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" name="btn_add" id="btn_add" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">+</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When for adding is clicked:

```
$("#btn_add").click(function() {
$("#invoice_table_data").append('<tr id="myTableRow'+'" ><td id="item_name'+n+'">'+item_name+'</td><td id="item_code'+n+'"> '+item_code+'</td><td id="description'+n+'">'+description+'</td><td><button type="button" name="delete_" id="delete_" data-idx="'+n+'">x</button></td></tr>');
n+=1;
```

And my delete function:

```
$('#delete_').click( function () {
var nb=$(this).data('idx');
$("#last_row"+nb).remove();
});
```

However when I click on delete nothing seems to happen. Can anybody help?

Comment: Ids have to be unique. The `<tr>` and `<button>` elements will share the same id

Comment: `$('#delete_').click()` this is an id selector. Ids have to be unique, so you have to change this. Also, the node ahs to be appended to the DOM before you can select it to add the event. Also, it would be way easier to not delete the last row, just add any new rows Above the last row, so the last row inetrface can just stay the same all the time.

Comment: First and foremost, ids must be unique on the page - no duplicates are allowed. Also, click handlers that are assigned using `$('...').click( ... )` do not apply to items that are added after that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Identifiers in HTML must be unique**, So create the element using CSS class. then `Class Selecctor` can be used.

Change script to render *HTML* as

```
<button type="button" class="delete_">x</button>
```

Currently what you are using is called a "direct" binding which will only attach to element that exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

Use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) method with [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) approach while generating elements dynamically. *So change your code to*

```
$("#invoice_table_data").on('click', ".delete_", function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

```js
var n = 1;
$("#btn_add").click(function() {
  $("#invoice_table_data").append('<tr><td>item_name' + n + '</td><td><button type="button"  class="delete_" data-idx="' + n + '">x</button></td></tr>');
  n += 1;
});

$("#invoice_table_data").on('click', ".delete_", function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="invoice_table_data">
  <tr id="last_row">
    <td id="item_name"></td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" name="btn_add" id="btn_add" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">+</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `$(document).on('click', ".delete_", function()`
Why can't I use what I did instead?
`$('#delete_').click(function(){`

Comment: @eBourgess, When page loads `#delete_` doesn't exists so with which element event will be attached? I have already answered it _Currently what y....._

Answer (score 1):

Use `attribute selector` and `event delegation`

```
$(document).on('click', "[id^='delete_']", function () {
  var nb=$(this).data('idx');
   $("#last_row"+nb).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$('document').on('click', '#delete_', function () {
    var nb=$(this).data('idx');
    $("#last_row"+nb).remove();
 });
```

You need to use on method, since your delete button not yet been exists.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it was partial

Answer (score 1):

Change your script which is dynamically adding the delete button to give the button a class name of btnDelete or something similar.

```
$("#btn_add").click(function() {
$("#invoice_table_data").append('<tr id="myTableRow'+'" ><td id="item_name'+n+'">'
+item_name+'</td><td id="item_code'+n+'"> '
+item_code+'</td><td id="description'+n+'">'
+description+'</td><td><button type="button" class="btnDelete" name="delete_" id="delete_" data-idx="'+n+'">x</button></td></tr>');
n+=1;
});
```

Then the script for your delete button is:

```
$("body").on("click", ".btnDelete", function (e) {
var rowToDelete = $(this).closest("tr");
rowToDelete.remove();
});
```

http://codepen.io/ailinmcc666/pen/ZBgXBZ

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer

Answer (score 1):

You have two separate problems.

## Problem 1

You can't have the same `id` multiple times on the page. That's just a basic rule of HTML. You can only use it once. If you use the same `id` more than once, only the first time will be counted.

**Solution**

If you want to be able to target multiple elements, use classes, or target a single parent and grab it's children using `element.firstElementChild`

---

## Problem 2

When you write `.click`, you are telling the browser to watch for when a user clicks on the element that you are targeting.

However, that element has to exist when the page first loads. That is because the lines of Javascript are only parsed once by the browser. It reads through your code, and if the element you want to click on doesn't exist right then, your code is skipped.

**Solution**

So what you have to do to address this is to add the event listener, the `.click`, onto an element which isn't dynamic. Remember that every click event gets passed up the chain, from the inner most element that the user clicked on, to that element's parent, to the next parent, and so on until it reaches the `body` element. So if you add a `.click` onto the parent of your list, it'll be attached correctly.

Using jQuery, it would be something like:

```
$('#invoice_table_data').on('click', 'button.delete', function(event){
    //run code here
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer